# Choosing the right MOSFET for 5V power relays

Tags: mosfet, switches

I am planning following circuit
[image: mosfet_circuit]
PR_SIG: a 5V logic level coming from a uC
+5V: is powered trough a external power supply (max 10A)
Power_relay: 5V, needs 70mA to switch

My problem now is choosing the 'right' MOSFET. I used the search on Mouser using the parameters that come to mind:
 - Vgs = 5V
 - Id > 250mA (3x70mA when all relays are switched on)
 - Another parameter is the power loss, but can also be neglected

With my research I found two candidates
[PMF250XNEX](https://www.mouser.at/ProductDetail/Nexperia/PMF250XNEX?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2FWiwHIj%2F%2F1rPuio7hhkYjv6SzWJ6AensS6vw%3D%3D),
[DMG1012TQ-7](https://www.mouser.at/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/DMG1012TQ-7?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2FWi427zbI4nt8D5Ve99lnuPWvU7W8FTsHf9A%3D%3D)

Comparing the two both should work as switch but I am not sure that I consider all necessary parameters, since there are ~450 different MOSFETS which apply to my search.

Do I need to look at more characteristics or can I choose the MOSFET using only Vgs and Id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since relays are **a lot** slower than any MOSFET, your only concern are the DC parameters.

The MOSFET must be able to handle a \$V_{GS}\$ > 5 V

The MOSFET must be able to handle a \$I_D\$ > 250 mA

You also need to be sure that the MOSFET switches on properly when you apply \$V_{GS}\$ = 5 V.

When the MOSFET is switched on it needs to have a low enough resistance \$R_{DS,on}\$ so that it will not drop much voltage. At only 250 mA a value of less than 0.5 ohm should be OK. Many MOSFETs will have a much lower \$R_{DS,on}\$.

It is also OK to use a **hugely** overspecified MOSFET. For example, if you have some MOSFETs lying around that are large and can handle 20 A but their size isn't an issue, you could use them, I mean, that would work fine.

The two MOSFETs you found look quite expensive to me. To keep things cheap (and for hobby projects, not professional use) I look on Ebay and find the cheapest MOSFETs which can do the job. A very common and cheap type is the [AO3400](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3400.pdf) which costs around 10 Euro cents (including shipping) if you buy 20 from China.

Comment: We have some MOSFETS here which are indeed highly overpowered for the task (up to 50A, 150V). I read in some literature that the input capacitance should not exceed 100pF in order to switch it using a uC. Reducing Rds(on) makes also sense.

Comment: I have the luxury that I do not need to look at the prices (only 2 PCBs are needed).

Comment: *I read in some literature that the input capacitance should not exceed 100pF in order to switch it using a uC* Next time, when you read that ask yourself: **Why?**. I can **guarantee** you that even when the input capacitance of a MOSFET is 10 nF (that's 100x 100 pF) it will work **just fine** when switching something on/off slowly (as will be the case with a relay). For a PWM signal, sure then speed matters more and the load capacitance should be limited. But for switching some relays: the capacitance really doesn't matter much.

Comment: Makes sense for slow switching speeds. Thanks